# Button click to show overlay over image (only CSS)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve that when you click the yellow circle with fa-icon inside that then the overlay shows over my image. Now the overlay shows below the image (green background with white text). My overlay code works, to see that, change `div id="overlay"` to `div class="overlay"`.
How to make the button click show my overlay over the image (no javascript)?

```css
/*@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {*/
  .button i {
    padding: 8px 13px;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-border-radius: 180px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 180px;
    border-radius: 180px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 20%;
  }
/*}*/

.button i:hover {
  color:#FFF;
  background-color:#000;
 }

/*@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {*/
  .product-detailscar:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
  }
/*}*/

.product-detailscar {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.intro, .userfield1car {
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:22px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:green;
 }

.product-detailscar .overlay {
  /*.well.carousel .overlay {*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: left;
  border-top: 1px solid #A10000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A10000;
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="product-detailscar">
            <div class="image-video-linksidebar">
                <img alt="#" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200">
                
              <div class="read-more"><a href="#overlay" class="button"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
            </div>
            <div id="overlay">
                <div class="intro">
                    Intro description car
                </div>
                <div class="userfield1car">
                    Userfield-1-car
                </div>
                <div class="userfield1car">
                    Userfield-2-car
                </div>
                <div class="userfield1car">
                    Userfield-3-car
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       <!--</div>--></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following part to your CSS:

```
#overlay {
  display: none;
}

#overlay:target {
  display: block;
}
```

And then in your code change:

```
.product-detailscar .overlay
```

To:

```
#overlay
```

And change opacity to more then 0, ex. 0.5;

Note that it will only work one way, so it will only show the overlay. If you want to show/hide overlay in pure CSS, the checkbox hack is the way to go. For more info check https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Updated example (no checkbox hack):

```css
  .button i {
    padding: 8px 13px;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-border-radius: 180px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 180px;
    border-radius: 180px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 20%;
  }

.button i:hover {
  color:#FFF;
  background-color:#000;
 }

  .product-detailscar:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
  }

.product-detailscar {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.intro, .userfield1car {
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:22px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:green;
 }

#overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: left;
  border-top: 1px solid #A10000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A10000;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

#overlay:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="product-detailscar">
            <div class="image-video-linksidebar">
                <img alt="#" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200">
                
              <div class="read-more"><a href="#overlay" class="button"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
            </div>
            <div id="overlay">
                <div class="intro">
                    Intro description car
                </div>
                <div class="userfield1car">
                    Userfield-1-car
                </div>
                <div class="userfield1car">
                    Userfield-2-car
                </div>
                <div class="userfield1car">
                    Userfield-3-car
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       <!--</div>--></a>
    </div>
```

BTW, it is a good idea to clean up your code ;)

Comment: BRILLIANT! Thanks a lot, I wanted to add a `cancel` button to your solution for the show/hide effect, but your proposed checkbox-hack is much nicer. Thanks again!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can move the overlay div just beneath the image-video-linkssidebar class like this:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="product-detailscar">
            <div class="image-video-linksidebar">
              <div id="overlay">
                <div class="intro">
                    Intro description car
                </div>
                <div class="userfield1car">
                    Userfield-1-car
                </div>
                <div class="userfield1car">
                    Userfield-2-car
                </div>
                <div class="userfield1car">
                    Userfield-3-car
                </div>
            </div>
                <img alt="#" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200">

              <div class="read-more"><a href="#overlay" class="button"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       <!--</div>--></a>
    </div>
```

Then add these styles to overlay:

```
position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
```

Comment: cannot get it right, can you show me in working code snippet please?